# Have a specific docstring for each methods in @action, Django-REST-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

In Django-REST-framework, in a `ViewSet`, I use extra routing actions using the `@action` decorator on several methods.
I would like to have different docstrings for each methods, but obviously this doesn't work.
Any idea?

```python
@action(methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def followers(self, request, player):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        """
        Get the players who follow this player
        """
        [...]

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        """
        Follow this player
        """
        [...]

    [...]
```

Generated doc with Swagger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kzUw.png

Answer (score 1):

Any method may have only one docstring, so generally you have two options:

1. You can define a single docstring to the `followers` method and explain how method behaves accordingly to the method. This option is suitable if you are sure that the business logic of the different HTTP methods is not too complex.
2. Define separate methods for different request types, so that they could have separate docstrings. This will allow you to keep the logic inside each method as simple as possible.

You can also consider returning an object that has separate methods representing the HTTP methods and calling them accordingly.

Comment: If I define several `@action` with the same urls (ie followers here), only the last defined exists. Seems like it overwrite the previous defined functions.

Comment: You can define them with different names and as private functions.